# mongodb,update array in collection error

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections

**mongodb version: 2.6.0**

**collecton fields:**

```
books{
       _id,
       chatpers : [    //a book has many chatpers, so the "chatpers" is an Array.
                    { 
                        _id,
                        _parentId,
                        text
                     }
                   ]
}
```

and the query that I run was:

```
db.books.update({
    _id : ObjectId("5354725719980e913e9be3f1"),
    "chapters._id" : "93cdb3d14da841aabde0dd65aa2fa343"
}, {
    "$set" : {
        "chapters.$.text" : "5.3 Handler",
        "chapters.$._parentId" : "ef5c3f14147f417b936221db00deff38"
    }
});
```

**problem :** when the length of chapters is small, it works well. when the length of the chapters grows beyond 120+ ,the mongodb reports an error, then shut down:

```
2014-11-04T18:44:00.759-0700 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2014-11-04T18:44:00.761-0700 Error: error doing query: failed at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:416
2014-11-04T18:44:00.765-0700 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2014-11-04T18:44:00.766-0700 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-04T18:44:00.766-0700 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
```

Thanks very much for your kindness guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I upgraded my mongodb version to 2.6.5, the problem was resovled.